# Python PDF split pages to specific path

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, pypdf

I have created a function for a PDF page Splitter. I can choose a PDF file, save the path to pdfOne and after that I can choose what pages I want to split. The problem is that split pages goes in the same path as the original PDF. I don't want that, I want to send the split pages to a different folder-path.

```
def onFindPage(self, event):

    pdfOne = self.pdfOne.GetValue()
    spgcf=int(self.spgcfrom.GetValue())
    spgcu=int(self.spgcuntil.GetValue())

    inputpdfpdfOne = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file(pdfOne, "rb"))

    for i in xrange((spgcf-1),spgcu):

        output = PdfFileWriter()            
        output.addPage(inputpdfpdfOne.getPage(i))
        with open("page%s.pdf" % i,"wb") as outputStream:
           output.write(outputStream)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to construct a path to the destination file:

```
import os.path

[...]

outputFilename = os.path.join(destination_directory, "page%s.pdf" % i)
with open (outputFilename, "wb") as outputStream:
    output.write(outputStream)
```

You can use `..`for the parent directory, `/` for the root directory

Comment: glad to help :-)